# htaccess url redirect/rewrite of specific url and remove query string (not preserving)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Current URL : http://www.domain.com/billing/signup.php?a=1&b=2

What I need : http://billing.domain.com/register.php

I'm not really good at htaccess syntax so I would like to ask for some help here. I don't need the query string anymore as the old url is already expired and I only need a 301 redirect to the new URL with the query string removed.

Any help would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root for the `www.domain.com` domain, you can do one of 2 things.

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signup\.php$ http://billing.domain.com/register.php? [R=301,L]
```

Or using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/signup.php http://billing.domain.com/register.php?
```

This completely ignores what the query string actually is. It just matches against the URI, `/signup.php` and redirects to the target. Note that the `?` at the end makes sure the existing query string doesn't get appended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the second method and it worked!